# Load more return duplicate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I trying to make load more content from database via php and ajax and read some tutorial but what I tried return duplicate entry. *(here is just an example of my real code:)*

**Query:**

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE cat = 2 LIMIT 10";
```

This load first 10 items.

**Query for load more:**

```
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$current = $_GET['current'];

$sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE cat = 2 LIMIT $current OFFSET $limit";
```

**Ajax:**

```
$('.getMore').click(function() {
  var adslen = $('.Ads').length; // this return current items
  var limit = $(this).attr('data-limit'); // this return current item and items after load more

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      limit: limit,
      current: adslen
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    url: '/api/fetch.php?getBrowse',
    success: function(data) {
      // do something
    }
  });

});
```

For example now we have 10 items, after click on loadMore it load another 10 items, but the problem is it load duplicate itemes too, what I have done wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<a class="getMore" id="browse-getMore" data-limit="10">More</a>
```

After press load more it update data-limit:

```
<a class="getMore" id="browse-getMore" data-limit="20">More</a>
```

Comment: Why do you think it loads duplicates? It seems like `name` is not a primary key and may contain duplicates

Comment: @Jacobian I load `id` too, I just made my code short as example, I note that in my question. `id` is unique and primary. my real code is so huge to put here.

Comment: Off topic: don't use variables directly because SQL Injection

Comment: @Robert this is example code, not real . but thank you for this. I aware that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not specify order. In your case  `SELECT` statement returns rows with no specific order. When you run it once, it may return one list of records, when you run it twice (the same select query) it may return another set of records. So, do it like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE cat = 2 ORDER BY id LIMIT $current OFFSET $limit";
```

And read theory. It says that relation (or table) is an unordered set of records, unless you specify order explicitly. And by the way, if you specify order, it is no longer a relation, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I added `ORDER BY ads.id` *in my real code* but still return duplicate, it return something like this: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 => after load more => 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 3 - 2 - 1

Comment: It can not be true, because records are ordered by id. So the sequence `4-5-3-2` is simply impossible.

Comment: I guess, there is some issue with you client code and not the server one.

Comment: Is it need to share real code? or? I really get this result.

Comment: There is a server side and there is a client side. Server side may return a valid result (just check Network tab inside developer tools of you browser), while the client side may produce some garbage. Check it at least to understand where the problem lies - on server or client side.

Comment: Here is the result: **Request URL** `myurl.com/api/fetch.php?getBrowse&limit=10&current=10` and response return same thing as view.

Comment: Click on Response tab and see the actual result, that your server side returns.

Comment: Yes, I already check this, it return some duplicate items, it's not skip current items.

Comment: Then check resultset right after you execute your sql query (by `var_dump` for example).

Comment: And by the way, you can have duplicates because of `LEFT JOINs`in your query. Minimize your query, remove all these joins and check that now there are no longer any duplicates.

Comment: You were right, after I remove `LEFT JOIN` it return correct items. so what should I do in this case?

Comment: You have two options - either use `GROUP BY ads.id` or `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I involved with cache .. I don't understand why a php file cached! I tried same `ORDER` solution in another browser, It works fine. Thank you for your kindly help.